# Error while executing select query in Hive - how to update Hadoop version

Tags: apache, hadoop, hive, hiveql

I am currently using hadoop 1.0.3 version. I recently installed Apache Hive to run with it. I was running the select * query which gave me an NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobConf.unset

I further found out its a compatibility issue with my current version of hadoop and requires me to upgrade to 1.2 or later.

I am fairly new to hadoop and would like to upgrade my current version to 1.2 or later. How do I go about doing the same.

I could not find any resources online to do so.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just download hadoop 1.2.x from [here](https://archive.apache.org/dist/hadoop/core/hadoop-1.2.1/) and do necessary configuration changes in your new hadoop. Change `HADOOP_HOME` to point to your new hadoop folder.

> **NOTE:** Change all the environmental variables (including .bashrc) to point to your new hadoop.